# It's better simply returning true/false or return the variable?

Tags: java

In a method I made this

```
@Override
public boolean canEditHq(User user, LocalEvent localEvent) {
    if (!HQ.equals(user.getUserHierarchy())) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!SECOND_APPROVAL.equals(localEvent.getStatus())) {
        return false;
    }

    final boolean hqCanApprove = this.parameterValueService.findByFullPath(user, HQ_APPROVAL).getValueAsBool();
    if (!hqCanApprove) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Sonarqube and my workmate tells that I can avoid writing the last if and simply return the `hqCanApprove` .

In my opinion I prefer the plain `return true/false` instead of returning the variable. What do you think?

Comment: I think this is just a matter of style / personal taste. I personally would prefer to return the variable.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with you

Comment: Adding new conditions will not change the lines so the lines of code will be kept to a minimum. However, I want the code to be the simplest to read. On this moment the thought process is a bit longer: "when the variable is not true, return false else return true", which is harder to process then "return the variable".
When you do change it, it will probably complain about a redundant variable. This is something I would ignore

Comment: I don't think the closing reason *opinion based* works well for CodeReview@SE. In a comparative review, I *want* opinions - rationalisations/motives welcome.

Comment: (I'd prefer just returning a single boolean expression. Even using less negations…)

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like that?

```
@Override
public boolean canEditHq(User user, LocalEvent localEvent) {
    return HQ.equals(user.getUserHierarchy())
        && SECOND_APPROVAL.equals(localEvent.getStatus()) 
        && !this.parameterValueService.findByFullPath(user, HQ_APPROVAL).getValueAsBool();
}
```

It would be even readible, if you make some abstraction levels in your code and your User and LocalEvent classes weren't anemic

Something like that (don't know if the domain logic is interpreted right there):

```
@Override
public boolean canEditHq(User user, LocalEvent localEvent) {
    return user.isHQ()
        && localEvent.needsSecondApproval()
        && notInHQApproval(user);
}

private boolean notInHQApproval(User user){
    return !this.parameterValueService.findByFullPath(user, HQ_APPROVAL).getValueAsBool();
}
```